# take screen short iphone when app is running background

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode

thanks helping me I am poor in English.

Calling this method every 1 min from  NSTimer. I need capture Activity happens in iPhone, not my application....  I tried with bellow code it will take my application screen.... I need to take iPhone screen short... 
example user opens safari and types URLthen I need to take that screen capture from my app it is possible.
if it is possible how to achieve that.

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.window.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

} else {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.window.bounds.size);

}

[self.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

if (imageData) {

    [imageData writeToFile:@"screenshot.png" atomically:YES];

} else {

    NSLog(@"error while taking screenshot");

}
```

Comment: There is no way that this could ever pass App Store review. (This isn't how you'd do it even if you didn't care about App Store review; your UIWindow has nothing to do with other app's UIWindow. I don't know any access to the `CGWindowList` or `CGDisplay` or `CVDisplayLink` on iOS, which are various ways to do this on macOS, even if you were on a jailbroken device. But outside of jailbreaks, I am very confident in saying this would never be approved.)

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is NO.

Support for background execution must be declared in advance by the app that uses them.

Below are the Background modes for apps
[image]

Please read this link for more information : [iOS BackgroundExecution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)